# TVS MSP240 Dot Matrix printer paper rollback

Tags: vb.net, printing, dot-matrix

I am using  [TVS MSP240](http://www.tvs-e.in/product-detail-db.aspx?id=17&typ=btn_bt&pro=tb_1) dot matrix printer with VB.NET and have a printing issue.

Paper size is 6x4. However, if I print using this size, I get incomplete text, but with 6x5 I get complete text.

But with this approach, paper scrolls one inch extra. Is there a way to scroll the paper back by one inch ?

Comment: did u solved it? if yes how?

Comment: nope. The user at the start if the day has to scroll back the page by a inch manually.